# How can I learn ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am an absolute beginner at ASP.NET. How can I learn it better?

Currently I am reading ebooks. Can you suggest better ways, or other ways, I can learn ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As everyone else suggested you, I suggest [asp.net learning pages](http://www.asp.net/learn/), too. But first of all reading a book on topic is a better way I think. Because books are well structured to learn something.

Also take a look at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605634/would-c-be-a-good-language-to-learn-for-web-development/605646#605646) if you're also new to .net or web development.

And one more thing, find a project for yourself to improve your skills and to implement what you learn. Develop your own blog, your own wiki, or whatever you like.

Comment: The referenced question does not exist anymore

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the Apress books. I don't know if they are translated.

ASP.NET: http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598931

ASP.NET MVC: http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430210078

Comment: These are the two best resources for learning ASP.Net in any medium.  The APress "PRO" books are really very good if you want take on the low level concepts.

Comment: Thanks but i already buy it from amazon

Answer (score 3):

Learn ASP.NET
http://www.asp.net/learn/

Answer (score 3):

I would say [Beginning ASP.NET 3.5: In C# and VB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047018759X)  would be a good read and after that [Professional ASP.NET 3.5: In C# and VB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187573) .. because I actually own both of these books

Keep in mind reading these books will only give you a foundation of what to expect, but you wll only get the full understanding by using asp.net yourself

Answer (score 2):

I would start out at [ASP .NET Learning Pages](http://www.asp.net/learn/)

They have plenty of videos ranging from beginners to more advanced stuff... Great resource...
G

Answer (score 2):

The best way, of course, is to actually build a website in asp.net ...

Comment: Yeah good  i try to build some test project

Answer (score 2):

You can learn asp from multiple sites it won't be that hard to find with google?

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials

I do have multiple positive experiences with this site.

It also contains some videos

I also checked this site it seems okay but didn't fully check it.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-view-controller-Step-by-Step-in-7

If you want to have you asp.net skills pushed a bit I really advice to go to an event like the Microsoft TechDays. For students like you there are depending on your country free days.
During those days or day you can ask questions to the experts giving the sessions.

Or watching an other programmer code is a mind opening experience.

I hope my answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of books and it is very easy to get lost in it all. My first run in with ASP.NET was the MVC3 framework, which I ended up liking quite abit!

The tutorials found here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight are free and proved invaluable to further my understanding of the framework.

In addition to the tutorials I would advice you to maybe brush up on some jQuery as it is an active part of the dynamic elements on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a video tutorial series, just follow a long and actually write every line of code you see.

there are several sites for this just search for "video asp.net tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

Read book and solve your problem with the knowledge you get from there.

Being in the same position as you but with Struts and Java I found very useful to ask questions on Stackoverflow to the questions I couldn't find any answer in the book.

Answer (score 1):

the asp.net website has a lot of (video) tutorials on many subjects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the learning section of the official ASP.NET website:

http://www.asp.net/learn/

Also, check out the [Murach books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774480).

Comment: are you give me it's books sample chapter

Comment: The link is to Amazon, you can go in and view sample pages on the Amazon site. "Murach" is the publisher of a range of beginners' books :-)

Answer (score 1):

Read books as the other posters have suggested. This will let you know what you can and can't do (easily). After reading a book then build a website and learn the rest through experience.
Then get a more advanced book and go through the same process. :)

Answer (score 1):

practice while you watch http://www.asp.net/learn

There are a plenty of videos for a basic user and you can take it from there..

Forget not to practice!!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn asp.net is by practice. Walk through some tutorials, build some things you like yourself. You might even wanna try to get someone's code and just look through it so you can addept way's off approaching things in asp.net.
And if you just google after "asp.net learn" or "asp.net tutorial" like all other users did posting comments before me, you can actually find alot of info.

GL,

Younes

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this book, I reading it right now and it's well categorized from the beginner level to advanced

[ASP.NET 4 Step by Step](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735627017)

,try to watch videos on [ASP.NET/Learn](http://www.asp.net/get-started) is simple and useful, and try to watch [TechEd](http://www.msteched.com/) and [MIX](http://live.visitmix.com/) videos to keep yourself updated what new in the technology.

Answer (score 0):

[W3Schools.com](http://w3schools.com) is one of the best website to learning for beginners.

Comment: Please _never_ suggest W3Schools, especially to beginners; it is [misleading, error prone and teaches incorrect practices](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Its not something that you should start by reading through all the details. After learning the basic concepts and how it works (you can find this information on google easily) you should deal with more code and projects. I suggest that think of a project and try to code it from scratch.

Here you can find some projects with source codes:
http://www.dotnetspider.com/projects/

If you cannot think of a projects, just pick a project from the list. Code it on your own and compare the result and approach of yours with the one in the given source code.