# Beginning ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I guess the title gives most of my question away, I have a university project in which I must design and create a website in php or asp.net I have chosen the asp.net path since I am pretty familiar in php and I prefer C# to php.. Could someone please reference some good online places to visit to do some further learning, and recommend some books would appreciate it thanks.

Comment: You'll get a better response, or links to previous questions on Stack Overflow. You don't have to do post again though, the question will be migrated automatically. Just create an account over there and associate your two accounts to keep ownership of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several questions from StackOverflow that may help:

- [Best way to learn C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287927/best-way-to-learn-c)
- [How can I learn ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790257/how-can-i-learn-asp-net)
- [What’s the best way to learn C# quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893/whats-the-best-way-to-learn-c-quickly)
- [Quickest approach to learn C# programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746561/quickest-approach-to-learn-c-programming)

Answer (score 1):

-MSDN Library
-Book: CLR via C#, Apress Pro ASP.NET MVC (for ASP.NET MVC), and Pro ASP.NET 3.5 (Webform)

Answer (score 1):

I think the Wrox Problem-Design-Solution books are always good if you like tutorial style books.

[ASP.NET 3.5 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187581)

If you're looking at MVC, Microsoft has the excellent Nerddinner tutorial

[Nerddinner](http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/)

Answer (score 1):

MVC is overkill for a basic university project site. Get a basic site similar to what you need (Website or Web Application project), perhaps from the free community projects on the ASP.NET home site, and then follow the video tutorials there using the freely downloaded site as a starting point :-)

Comment: thanks but when i did this project mvc was a requirement to be able to get a first....